# Splitting Images into Individual Pixels/Blocks Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, sorting

I would like to create or find an algorithm that turns mazes like the ones attached, into an array in a list. All the black spaces can become a string, 'w' and all the white spaces can become 'b'.
Example (example is just a basic display, no maze):

```
    self.base_map = [
      ['w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'],
      ['w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','w'],
      ['w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','w'],
      ['w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','w'],
      ['w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','w'],
      ['w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','w'],
      ['w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','w'],
      ['w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','w'],
      ['w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w']
    ]
```

I think this can be done by splitting the image into blocks (attached) and scanning each one to see its color. I'm not sure though. If it helps, each of the mazes is 9x9, each block being 1.

Is there a library and algorithm that can help me here?

[image: Example Maze]

[image: Example Maze 2]

[image: Maze Blocks]

Comment: what image format do you have? Why strings and not boolean (true,false) or int (1,0) arrays? Have a look at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

Comment: The reason I don't have bool or int is because I want to translate the array into emojis. I only put 'w' and 'b' as an example. I would really want to do something like :white_square: and :black_square:

Comment: what image format do you have?

Comment: the maze image format is png

Comment: have a look at this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-image-ascii-image-python/

Comment: Your second image has 9x9 blocks. Your first and third seem to have white borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm autodetects the width of the walls and halls (assuming they are equal), but fails anyways, because the walls on the images do not have constant width.

Maybe is possible to adjust the coefficients by some linear regression.

The autodetection works by identifying the corners, and calculating the distances between closest corners.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def downloadImage(URL):
    """Downloads the image on the URL, and convers to cv2 RGB format"""
    from io import BytesIO
    from PIL import Image as PIL_Image
    import requests

    response = requests.get(URL)
    image = PIL_Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


URL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm8dr.png"

img = downloadImage(URL)

# Convert ot 2 color
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret3, th3 = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# plt.imshow(th3, cmap='gray')

# Detect corners
CornerKernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
corner = cv2.filter2D(th3//255, -1, CornerKernel)
# A corner add up to to 1 or 9
Corners = np.argwhere((corner == 4) | (corner == 8))
antiCorners = np.argwhere((corner == 1) | (corner == 5))
# for each point in Corners, find the closet point in antiCorners
Corner_antiCorner = []
for point in Corners:
    distances = np.linalg.norm(antiCorners-point, axis=1)
    closest = antiCorners[np.argmin(distances)]
    Corner_antiCorner.append((point+closest)/2)
    plt.plot([point[1], closest[1]], [point[0], closest[0]], color='r')
# For eachpoint in Corner_antiCorner, find the closet point in Corner_antiCorner
closestCorners = []
for point in Corner_antiCorner:
    distances = np.linalg.norm(Corner_antiCorner-point, axis=1)
    # closest is itself, so second closest is chosen
    closest = Corner_antiCorner[distances.argsort()[1]]
    closestCorners.append((point, closest))
    plt.plot([point[1], closest[1]], [point[0], closest[0]], color='r')

# Sample of separations dx,dy
dx = np.array([abs(p[1]-q[1]) for p, q in closestCorners])
dy = np.array([abs(p[0]-q[0]) for p, q in closestCorners])

mediandx = np.median(dx[dx > 0])
mediandy = np.median(dy[dy > 0])

# plt.scatter([p[1] for p in corners],[p[0] for p in corners])
# plt.scatter([p[1] for p in antiCorners],[p[0] for p in antiCorners])
plt.imshow(img)

stepY, stepX = int(mediandy), int(mediandx)
xrange = range(stepX//2, img.shape[0], stepX)
yrange = range(stepY//2, img.shape[1], stepY)
x, y = [], []
mazeElement = {0: 'b', 1: '█'}
for r in yrange:
    for c in xrange:
        x.append(c)
        y.append(r)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()

base_map = [[mazeElement[img[r, c]//255]
            for c in xrange if c < img.shape[1]] for r in yrange if r < img.shape[0]]
print(*["".join(row) for row in base_map], sep='\n')
```

[image]

```
████████████
█bbbbbbbbbb█
████████b█b█
█b█b█bb█b█b█
█b█b█bb█b█b█
█bbb█bb█b█b█
█b███bb███b█
█b█bbbbbb█b█
█b██████b███
█bbbbbbbbbb█
████████████
```

[image]

```
bbbbbbbbb
████b███b
b█b█b█b█b
b█b█b█b█b
b█b█bbb█b
b█b█████b
b█bbbbbbb
b████████
bbbbbbbbb
```

Comment: This works perfectly. However I would just like to point out that none of the code after the plt.show() runs.

Comment: Also is there a way to structure it like the way I structured it in my original question? Multiple arrays creating a list

Comment: It does not works perfectly. Look on the first result, it has halls with double 'b' width. The code will keep running after closing the window opened with plt.show()

Comment: The first screenshot I took was faulty. The second one with no white border was an accurate example of the mazes I needed to pump into the script. Also, do you know if you could answer my previous question about restructuring it?

Comment: I don't know which other question you are talking about

Comment: If all your images were clearer, it would be easy and fast. All it would be needed is to delete repeated columns and rows, and it would convert directly without any hassle

Comment: I ended up getting that figured out. But I need help with one more thing. Is it possible to create a different value for the start and end of the maze? I think the only thing required it to search for the first █ value in the first and last columns and alter it.

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking that. If you want a different character than █, you can use whatever you want. Just edit the character in the dictionary `mazeElement`. I used that character because is easy to watch. If you have difficulty writing it, you can write <alt>219, or copy paste it, or google "black square character" and copy paste the result, or use a charmap tool like Windows Character Map

Comment: I know how to change all the characters in the entire maze. But what I need is a specific character. maybe s and e. At the start and end of the maze

Comment: Your problem is deciding which point is the entrance. If you can visit each maze only once, then one is the entrance and other the exit, but if you can return, there is no entrance and exit, but just connections. There is also the matter of if the mazes are spatially coherent, then connected mazes have the connection at the place that links to the other maze. If the mazes are spatially coherent, then you need some data structure linking the mazes, like a graph, or a 3D array. Also, the entrance has to be linked to the halls (not buried inside walls).

Comment: Your question depends on the rest of your code, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246764/discussion-between-dre-and-colim).

Answer (score 0):

Your image has a variable width of walls, so the point grid is not perfect, but here you have the general idea.

You can just read the colors of the image, and round them to  0 (black), or 1 (white), to detect empty spaces and walls.

This code does not detects the number of rows and columns (I counted them and hardcoded 10 columns and 10 rows)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def downloadImage(URL):
    """Downloads the image on the URL, and convers to cv2 RGB format"""
    from io import BytesIO
    from PIL import Image as PIL_Image
    import requests

    response = requests.get(URL)
    image = PIL_Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


URL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm8dr.png"

img = downloadImage(URL)


plt.imshow(img)
x, y = [], []
columns = 10
rows = 10
stepY, stepX = img.shape[0]//rows, img.shape[1]//columns
xrange = range(0, img.shape[0], stepX)
yrange = range(0, img.shape[1], stepY)
mazeElement = {0: 'b', 1: '█'}
for r in yrange:
    for c in xrange:
        x.append(c)
        y.append(r)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()

base_map = [[mazeElement[round(sum(img[r, c][:])/3//255, 0)]
            for c in xrange] for r in yrange]
print(*["".join(row) for row in base_map], sep='\n')
```

[image]

it prints

```
███████████
█bbbbbbbbb█
███████b█b█
█b█b█b█b█b█
█b█b█b█b█b█
█bbb█b█b█b█
█b█bbbbb█b█
█b█████b███
█bbbbbbbbb█
███████████
```